# How to do reverse URL with keyword argument in Jinja2?

Tags: django, jinja2

In a view function we can do the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def SomeView(request):   
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse('blog:specific-topic', kwargs={'topic':'python'})
    )
```

In a template, without keyword argument, we can do this:

```
<a href="{{ url('home-page') }}">Home Page</a>
```

But how to do reverse URL in Jinja2 with keyword arguments?

I am developing a programming blog, so I need to organize articles into topics including Python, Dajngo, Jinja2, Designing Relational Databases, and so forth. I wrote the following:

```
<a href="{{ url('blog:specific-topic', topic.slug) }}" class="topic">{{ topic.name }}</a>
```

But it did not work.

Comment: What happens if you add topic as argument of your url c.f : `<a href="{{ url('blog:specific-topic', topic=topic.slug) }}" class="topic">{{ topic.name }}</a>` ?

Comment: I save topics in the a database table, so number of topics and their names are dynamic, they are not specified at development. I might some topics after the blog is running on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. First of all create a dictionary and add key-value pairs to it like Python syntax:

```
{% set kwargs_ = dict(topic_slug=article.topic.slug, article_slug=article.slug) %}
```

Then pass this dictionary to kwargs argument of reverse (in Jinja2 usually url) function:

```
<a href="{{ url('blog:specific-topic', kwargs=kwargs_) }}" class="topic">{{ topic.name }}</a>
```

And it works.